# Why I need a new primitive?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am learning functional programming in Scala and reading the book [FPiS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617290653).

One the page 131 about API design(algebra), the author mentioned following:

> As we discussed in chapter 7, we’re interested in understanding what
>   operations are primitive and what operations are derived, and in
>   finding a small yet expressive set of primitives. A good way to
>   explore what is expressible with a given set of primitives is to pick
>   some concrete examples you’d like to express, and see if you can
>   assemble the functionality you want. As you do so, look for patterns,
>   try factoring out these patterns into combinators, and refine your set
>   of primitives. We encourage you to stop reading here and simply play
>   with the primitives and combinators we’ve written so far. If you want
>   some concrete examples to inspire you, here are some ideas:

What does he mean with **expressive primitives**? What is a **primitive**?
(The chapter 7 does not explain about primitive at all.)

I am imaging, a primitive is a smallest thing of something that can be build with combinator to get a higher level thing.

The question from the book:

> If we can generate a single `Int` in some range, do we need a new primitive to
>   generate an `(Int,Int)` pair in some range?

What is the answer of the question?
Is `Int` a primitive?
What is a primitive function?

Comment: @UlugToprak No, that's not at all the kind of primitives this talks about.

Comment: Alright, i removed it thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is a primitive?
>
> I am imaging, a primitive is a smallest thing of something that can be build with combinator to get a higher level thing.

Right. So in this case: you are developing an API which has type `Gen[A]` denoting "a generator of values of type `A`". Combinators in this API will be methods which operate on `Gen`s and produce `Gen`s. However, you also need something to apply those combinators to: methods which produce `Gen`s without starting with one.

One of these may be `range(min: Int, max: Int): Gen[Int]`. If you now need a `pairInRange(min: Int, max: Int): Gen[(Int, Int)]`, do you need to implement it in the same way `range` is implemented, or can you build it from `range` using combinators? And if you can, what combinators do you need? In this case, you should conclude that

```
def pairInRange(min: Int, max: Int) = pair(range(min, max), range(min, max))
```

is a reasonable implementation, assuming there is a `pair` combinator (think what its type should be), so `pairInRange` doesn't need to be a primitive: it's a *derived* operation. Primitive operations are those which aren't derived.

You could equally have `pairInRange` as primitive and `def pair(min: Int, max: Int) = pairInRange(min, max).map(_._1)` as derived; this is just an unnatural way to design it!

> (The chapter 7 does not explain about primitive at all.)

Now that I've got home and have access to the book: yes, it does. If you search for "primitive" in the book (assuming you have the electronic version), you'll find this quote in 7.1.3 Explicit forking:

> > The function `lazyUnit` is a simple example of a *derived* combinator, as opposed to a
> >     *primitive* combinator like `unit`. We were able to define `lazyUnit` just in terms of other
> >     operations. Later, when we pick a representation for `Par`, `lazyUnit` won’t need to
> >     know anything about this representation—its only knowledge of `Par` is through the
> >     operations `fork` and `unit` that are defined on `Par`.

Note in particular the last sentence, which makes a point I didn't emphasize above. You should also read what follows: there are more explanations in 7.3.

> What does he mean with expressive primitives?

A primitive is not expressive, it's a set of primitives (including combinators) that is expressive. That is, it should allow you to express not just `range` and `pairInRange` but all other generators you want.

> Is `Int` a primitive?

No. This is a meaning of "primitive" unrelated to "primitive types" (`Int`, `Double`, etc.)

Comment: How would you describe a primitve, if someone ask you?

Comment: First of all, thanks so much for your answer. The last question, what does the author mean about `representation`?

Comment: How `Par` (or `Gen`, or other types in your API) is actually defined: e.g. its private members, extending another class, etc. as opposed to what's part of your API.

Comment: Thanks so much alexey for help.